# do modern OEM brake pads contain asbestos?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor

While changing the oil today in a friend's shop (USA), someone grinded a OEM Ford brake pad that seems a few years old. The brake pad model number is Ford GA 8135 FG, and I was about 20 feet away. He grinded for a bit before I realized what's going on and walked away.

I wonder how likely I was exposed to asbestos?

thanks

Comment: No, they do not contain asbestos, since 1980s (Europe) and 1990s (US). It's good though, to avoid breathing in any fine powder.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, asbestos was never banned in brake products in the US though.

Comment: It was [supposed to be](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1991-02-14-vw-1368-story.html) but I see now it was defeated by Congress (or should I say interested parties). Unbelievable.